# Insert table in a cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to reach the following result

[[image: Target reference]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAqrb.png)

And so far what I have is this:

[[image: Progress]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISIgq.png)

This is my code:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.shared import Cm


Document = Document()
Table = Document.add_table(rows=2, cols=2)

# Rows Config
for row in Table.rows:
    row.height = Cm(11)
    row.width = Cm(8.02)

for x in range(3 + 1):
    ParaGraph = Table.cell(0,x).paragraphs[0]
    ParaGraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
    Run = ParaGraph.add_run()
    Run.add_picture("image.png", width = Cm(6), height = Cm(7))
Document.save("FILE.docx")
```

In summary I am looking to make a 2x2 "mother" table where each cell has the specified length, that inside each cell there is another 1x2 table where the top cell measures 6cm x 7cm, and the bottom cell measures 6cm x 1.4, and that inside the first cell there is an image of the same size as the cell.

As you can see I have no problem in creating the table and inserting the images, I have no problems with the measures, what I have not managed to do is to insert another table in the cells of the "mother" table, I have not got specific information about it. Thank you.

Comment: There is a `_Cell.add_table()` method. Is that what you're looking for? https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table._Cell.add_table

Comment: Thanks, I swear I went through that whole page and I didn't see that method.

Answer (score 0):

Just so the question is not left unanswered here is the solution, thanks to Scanny's comment.

[_Cell.add_table](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table._Cell.add_table)